# Spring boot CORS config with ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, configurationproperties

I have a global CORS configuration which is working well:

```
@Component
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    String allowedOrigins = "*";

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
    }

    public String getAllowedOrigins() {
        return allowedOrigins;
    }

    public void setAllowedOrigins(String allowedOrigins) {
        this.allowedOrigins = allowedOrigins;
    }
}
```

Now I want to make the `allowsOrigins`field dynamic for each application through `application.yaml`. I tried to add `@ConfigurationPropierties(prefix="cors")` to the `CorsConfiguration` Class. And added `cors.allowedOrigins=test` to `application.yaml`. But this does nothing. I have read many posts and tutorials, but I don't get why this isn't working. It should be as easy as that. What am I missing?

**EDIT** I also tried `@Value` annotation like this

```
@Value("${cors.allowedOrigins:*}")
String allowedOrigins;
```

Application.yaml

```
cors:
  allowedOrigins=http://localhost:4200
```

Result is that I only get the default value `*`, nothing is read from `application.yaml`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `@Value` annotation to get your property value from `application.yml` like this :

**application.yml**

```
origin:
  allowedOrigins: [HOST_HERE]
```

And then use it in your **CorsConfiguration** class :

```
@Component
public class CorsConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Value("${origin.allowedOrigins:DEFAULT_VALUE_HERE}")
  private String allowedOrigins;

  @Override
  public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
      registry.addMapping("/**")
            .allowedOrigins(allowedOrigins)
  }
  // code here
}
```

Comment: Same problem. Default value is used but not the one from the application.yaml

Comment: can you update your post by showing what you've done ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the following annotation on CorsConfiguration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "<packge name>" })
```

the last one is not essential but sometimes you need it

Answer (score -1):

### Manual way

I recommended for you making Configuration Class, like this

```java
@lombok.Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cors")
public class PathCorsConfiguration {
    @Nullable
    private String[] allowedOrigins;
}
```

`application.yml`

```yml
cors:
  allowedOrigins:
    - "https://www.someurl_1.com"
    - "https://www.someurl_2.com"
```

and for highlighting new properties in config file you may add annotation processor:

```xml
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
    <annotationProcessorPaths>
      <annotationProcessorPath>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </annotationProcessorPath>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

---

### Automatically way

Few years ago I asked to self the same question like you and recently I released self library for make it easily:
add dependency

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.iruzhnikov</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-webmvc-cors-properties-autoconfigure</artifactId>
  <version>VERSION</version>
</dependency>
```

and add configuration

```yml
spring:
  web:
    cors:
      enabled: true
      mappings:
        baseOrigins:
          paths: /**
          allowed-origins: "http://localhost:4200"
          allowed-origin-patterns: .*
```